# Android Studio / gradle not building shared library for x86_64

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use Android Studio to make an app with the NDK.

That involves building an `.so` file which my Java app then uses with `System.loadLibrary`.

Unfortunately, **the `.so` file is only built on ARM or x86, but gradle doesn't build it for the x86_64 `abiFilter`**.

My `build.gradle` (I'm using the [experimental Gradle plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) for Android Studio to get NDK support), with unrelated details stripped (the `productFlavors` has no details stripped):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {

        compileSdkVersion = 19
        buildToolsVersion = "23"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.example"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 14
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "JNIProcessor"
    }

    android.productFlavors {

        create("arm") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }

        create("x86") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "x86"
            }
        }

        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "x86_64"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I run `./gradlew installx86Debug --info`, I get in the output (formatted to multiple lines for easier reading):

```
Selected primary task 'installX86Debug' from project :
file or directory '/home/niklas/AndroidStudioProjects/androidcl/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/x86/debug', not found
Tasks to be executed: [
    task ':app:preBuild', 
    task ':app:preX86DebugBuild', 
    task ':app:checkX86DebugManifest', 
    task ':app:prepareX86DebugDependencies', 
    task ':app:compileX86DebugAidl', 
    task ':app:compileX86DebugRenderscript', 
    task ':app:generateX86DebugBuildConfig', 
    task ':app:generateX86DebugAssets', 
    task ':app:mergeX86DebugAssets', 
    task ':app:generateX86DebugResValues', 
    task ':app:generateX86DebugResources', 
    task ':app:mergeX86DebugResources', 
    task ':app:processX86DebugManifest', 
    task ':app:processX86DebugResources', 
    task ':app:generateX86DebugSources', 
    task ':app:processX86DebugJavaRes', 
    task ':app:compileX86DebugJavaWithJavac', 
    task ':app:copyX86DebugX86JNIProcessorSharedLibraryGdbServer', 
    task ':app:createX86DebugX86JNIProcessorSharedLibraryGdbsetup', 
    task ':app:compileX86DebugX86JNIProcessorSharedLibraryJNIProcessorMainCpp', 
    task ':app:linkX86DebugX86JNIProcessorSharedLibrary', 
    task ':app:stripSymbolsX86DebugX86JNIProcessorSharedLibrary', 
    task ':app:x86DebugX86JNIProcessorSharedLibrary', 
    task ':app:compileX86DebugSources', 
    task ':app:preDexX86Debug', 
    task ':app:dexX86Debug', 
    task ':app:validateDebugSigning', 
    task ':app:packageX86Debug', 
    task ':app:zipalignX86Debug', 
    task ':app:assembleX86Debug', 
    task ':app:installX86Debug'
]
```

If however I build for 64 bit with `./gradlew installx86-64Debug --info`, the output only contains (all `gradlew` output lines before these are identical for the two builds):

```
Selected primary task 'installX86-64Debug' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [
    task ':app:preBuild', 
    task ':app:preX86-64DebugBuild', 
    task ':app:checkX86-64DebugManifest', 
    task ':app:prepareX86-64DebugDependencies', 
    task ':app:compileX86-64DebugAidl', 
    task ':app:compileX86-64DebugRenderscript', 
    task ':app:generateX86-64DebugBuildConfig', 
    task ':app:generateX86-64DebugAssets', 
    task ':app:mergeX86-64DebugAssets', 
    task ':app:generateX86-64DebugResValues', 
    task ':app:generateX86-64DebugResources', 
    task ':app:mergeX86-64DebugResources', 
    task ':app:processX86-64DebugManifest', 
    task ':app:processX86-64DebugResources', 
    task ':app:generateX86-64DebugSources', 
    task ':app:processX86-64DebugJavaRes', 
    task ':app:compileX86-64DebugJavaWithJavac', 
    task ':app:compileX86-64DebugSources', 
    task ':app:preDexX86-64Debug', 
    task ':app:dexX86-64Debug', 
    task ':app:validateDebugSigning', 
    task ':app:packageX86-64Debug', 
    task ':app:zipalignX86-64Debug', 
    task ':app:assembleX86-64Debug', 
    task ':app:installX86-64Debug'
]
```

So these entries are missing for the 64 bit build:

```
    task ':app:copyX86DebugX86JNIProcessorSharedLibraryGdbServer', 
    task ':app:createX86DebugX86JNIProcessorSharedLibraryGdbsetup', 
    task ':app:compileX86DebugX86JNIProcessorSharedLibraryJNIProcessorMainCpp', 
    task ':app:linkX86DebugX86JNIProcessorSharedLibrary', 
    task ':app:stripSymbolsX86DebugX86JNIProcessorSharedLibrary', 
    task ':app:x86DebugX86JNIProcessorSharedLibrary',
```

which makes clear why my `.so` files is missing (e.g. the `link` task is not present).

**Why does gradle decide not to add the link step for my x86_64 `abiFilter`?**

Comment: I can get the missing targets by setting `compileSdkVersion = 23` and `targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23` instead of 19. But I still don't understand why.

Comment: may be because of support to x64 platform was introduced with API 21: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/x86-64.html#comp

Comment: @V-master I think you are right. I would have expected a "loud failure" instead of the "silently drop some of the build targets" (e.g. `link`) behaviour, but if you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: What if you have targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23 and compileSdkVersion = 19, it should build x64 libraries with newer headers automatically? At least that's what I've read somewhere, but it simply doesn't! No way to build a single APK on any API version?

Comment: Ok guys, I have a serious problem with this. It started happening out of nowhere, and now AndroidStudio doesn't build 64bit so files for ANY architecture (I've tried Intel, ARM and MIPS, and none of them builds), but it does build for ALL 32bit architectures. So what's happening and how can I solve this? Any help please? And important thing to mention, when I launch an app directly to a 64bit phone, it works, but 64-bit .so files are nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by setting the "platformVersion" **inside NDK tag** to 23 (probably just needs to be 21 or higher). So, NOT the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion values which are for Java part, but platformVersion value which is for NDK part.